# 4 selections should be written into the textarea on each change properly

Tags: jquery, select, textarea, onchange

My jq library loaded is jq_min_3.1.1.js. If matters, broser is IE11. my script is just below the form in html body.

What I require is: The last state of the 4 selections should be written into the textarea just after *each change in any of the selections*.

my trial last state:

http://jsbin.com/comolifeyo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Each selection has `<option value="">select</option>` in common.
for example `A | - | X | -` means, selection 2 & 4 were not selected or reselection was made to abort the previous selection (not to select).

It's important that if selection1 was selected as **A**, but then selected as **select** (no selection); then the textarea should change from **A** to **-**

I'm ok with PHP but I don't know jquery. Code below is an adaptation from codes I found from SO. I made F12 and console gives no error however my textarea is empty.

What I tried is below. It seems that `$imploded = $arr_out.join(' | ');` is not set since $arr_out at that point is not set. (console log at that point gives nothing).

What is wrong? Why is it wrong? Will the solution be crossbrowser if jq library is ok?

thanks

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="myform" id="myform">    
    <select name="select1" id="select1" size="1">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select2" id="select2" size="1">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">q1</option>
        <option value="2">q2</option>
        <option value="3">q3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select3" id="select3" size="1">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">X</option>
        <option value="2">Y</option>
        <option value="3">Z</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select4" id="select4" size="1">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">q7</option>
        <option value="2">q8</option>
        <option value="3">q9</option>
    </select>

    <textarea name="first_paste" id="first_paste" disabled></textarea>

</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $fields = ['#select1','#select2','#select3','#select4'];
    var $arr_out = [];

    $.each($fields, function(key,val)
    {

        $(val).change(function()
        {   
            if( $(val).val() === "" )
            {
                $arr_out[key] = '-';
                // console.log($arr_out.join(' | '));

            }
            else
            {
                $arr_out[key] = ($(val + ' option:selected').text());
                // console.log($arr_out.join(' | '));
            }
        });
    })
    // console.log($arr_out.join(' | '));
    $imploded = $arr_out.join(' | ');
    $('#first_paste').text($imploded);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="myform" id="myform">    
        <select name="select1" id="select1" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">select</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select2" id="select2" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">select</option>
            <option value="1">q1</option>
            <option value="2">q2</option>
            <option value="3">q3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select3" id="select3" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">select</option>
            <option value="1">X</option>
            <option value="2">Y</option>
            <option value="3">Z</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select4" id="select4" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">select</option>
            <option value="1">q7</option>
            <option value="2">q8</option>
            <option value="3">q9</option>
        </select>

        <textarea name="first_paste" id="first_paste" disabled></textarea>

    </form>


$(document).ready(function() {
    var $fields = ['#select1','#select2','#select3','#select4'];
    var $arr_out = [];

    $.each($fields, function(key,val)
    {
        if($(val).find(":selected").text() == "select" ){
        console.log($(val).find(':selected').text());
        $arr_out[key] = '-';
      }
      $("#first_paste").html($arr_out +"," + "" );
            console.log(key,val);
        $(val).change(function()
        {   
            switch (key) {
              case 0:
                    if($(val).find(":selected").text() == "select" ){
                        console.log($(val).find(':selected').text());
                        $arr_out[key] = '-';
                      break;
                  }  
                  else{
                      $arr_out[key] = $(val).find(":selected").text();
                      break;
                  }
              case 1:
                  if($(val).find(":selected").text() == "select" ){
                        console.log($(val).find(':selected').text());
                        $arr_out[key] = '-';
                      break;
                  }  
                  else{
                      $arr_out[key] = $(val).find(":selected").text();
                      break;
                  }
              case 2:
                  if($(val).find(":selected").text() == "select" ){
                        console.log($(val).find(':selected').text());
                        $arr_out[key] = '-';
                      break;
                  }  
                  else{
                      $arr_out[key] = $(val).find(":selected").text();
                      break;
                  }
              case 3:
                  if($(val).find(":selected").text() == "select" ){
                        console.log($(val).find(':selected').text());
                        $arr_out[key] = '-';
                      break;
                  }  
                  else{
                      $arr_out[key] = $(val).find(":selected").text();
                      break;
                  }
          }
              console.log($arr_out);
              $("#first_paste").html($arr_out +"," + "" );
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: I wrote in question that **It's important that if selection1 was selected as A, but then selected as select (no selection); then the textarea should change from A to -.** You removed `if else` statements. Please read the questions more carefully.

Comment: Updated the above code and here is the working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2522/

Comment: thank you so much. **May you please also tell me what is wrong in my code?** I don't like only copy-paste a working code and move on.

Comment: @AndreChenier: 
 Only mistake you did is that you were rendering array outside the function. Try to append array in both if and else block, Your code will work. Only thing remains is at the initial stage setting - at all four places. For that you need to write the selected attribute in option which you missed out . Sharing the updated fiddle of your code itself. Nothing new code in that except rendering in if and else and html attrib for option.

Cheers to your code

Hope now you can write code for initial rendering of - in Textarea

Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2583/